# Is it possible to describe predictable processes in terms of jumps they are allowed to have?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Is it possible to describe the family of predictable processes relative to a given filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$ satisfying usual assumptions in terms of the kinds of jumps they are allowed to have?

For the sake of simplicity, assume that $X$ is a сàdlàg martingale. If it is left-continuous, it is automatically predictable. On the other hand, if it is right-continuous, inaccessible jumps such as those of the Poisson process make is non-predictable, but a jump at deterministic time is okay for a predictable process, right?

Finally, is it correct to say that a process is predictable if the jumps at which it is not left-continuous are predictable?

---

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/359749/1132955) seem related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Theorem(cf. S. W. He et al., *Semimartingale Theory and Stochastic Calculus*, Sci. Press and CRC(1992). **Theorem 4.33**, pp126 or C. Dellacherie and P. Meyer, *Probabilities and Potential*, volume 29 of *North-Holland Mathematics Studies*.
North-Holland, Amsterdam, 1978. **Theorem 88C**, pp141-IV) may be useful for you.

**Theorem** Assume that $(\mathscr{F}_t)$ is complete. Let $X$ be a cadlag process. In order $X$ to be a predictable it is necessary and sufficient to satisfy the following conditions:

i) For each totally inaccessible time $S$, $X_S=X_{S-}$ a.s. on $[S<\infty]$;

ii) For each predictable time $T$, $X_TI_{[T<\infty]}$ is $\mathscr{F}_{T-}$-measurable.

Comment: Thank you very much! So I was close